# How I can grant permission for Pcap library in Windows 10 from C#?

Tags: pcap, raw-sockets, pcap.net, sharppcap, goose

I use SharpPcap library for realise GOOSE protocol listener (EtherType = 0x88B8). It works well, but only if I run Wireshark in parallel, otherwise my program does not catch GOOSE packets.

SharpPcap examples also don't capture GOOSE packets while Wireshark is not running. But SharpPcap library captures my broadcast UDP packets.

Comment: I tried switched off Firewall and antivirus, but GOOSE packets I can receive only if Wireshark started

Comment: I ran my program as an administrator, and this also does not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open my SharpPCap device in promiscuous mode:

```
winPcap.Open(SharpPcap.WinPcap.OpenFlags.Promiscuous | 
    SharpPcap.WinPcap.OpenFlags.NoCaptureLocal, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
```

My ethernet card did not accept other MAC addresses